# Как сравнить DateTime c Datetime и если они равны, то добавлять в список

Tags: c#

```
var query = _context.Orders.AsNoTracking();
var date = new DateTime(2023, 1, 08, 18, 30, 25);
var list = query.Where(x => x.Date == date);



public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: А сейчас что - не работает? Я бы посоветовал сравнивать не на точное равенство, а на то, что абсолютная разница даты-времени меньше секунды, например. Хотя зависит от задачи, может вам и правда нужна точная разница.

Comment: Мне нужна точная разница

Comment: var list = query.Where(x => x.Date == date).ToList();